# Envío de cookies para extracción de información

Tags: r, cookies, rvest

Estoy extrayendo información de productos de la página web de un supermercado. No tengo problemas para acceder al nombre, el fabricante, etc., pero no puedo acceder al dato de precios.

He escuchado que es posible enviar `cookies` al navegador para que no identifique que se trata de un bot, he buscado en muchos sitios pero no he encontrado una respuesta satisfactoria. Probablemente se puede con el uso del paquete `CRurl`, pero no estoy seguro.

¿Existe algún método para esto?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
> enlace<-"http://www.exito.com/products/0000228194195697/Crema+Dental+Sensodyne+Original+Tubo+90+gr"
> download.file(enlace, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
> doc<-read_html("scrapedpage.html")
> 
> # nnombre
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath='//*[@id="prd0000228194195697"]/div[1]/h1'))
[1] "<h1 class=\"name\">Crema Dental Sensodyne Original Tubo 90 gr</h1>"
> # fabricante
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath='//*[@id="prd0000228194195697"]/div[1]/h2'))
[1] "<h2 class=\"brand\">SENSODYNE</h2>"
> # plu
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath='//*[@id="prd0000228194195697"]/div[1]/div[1]'))
[1] "<div class=\"plu\"> PLU: 927050 </div>"
> # presentación
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath='//*[@id="prd0000228194195697"]/div[1]/div[2]'))
[1] "<div class=\"reference\"> Presentación: C</div>"
> # precio
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath='//*[@id="prd0000228194195697"]/div[3]/div[1]/p/span/text()'))
[1] ""
```

Comment: Intenta con el paquete `webshot` que genera un explorador virtual, puede que tengas más suerte ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Con `rvest` es posible hacer "login" a sitios y mantenerse en el contexto de una sesión logeada para hacer todas las operaciones de "scrapping" que necesitemos. Al menos esto funciona con logins clásicos, habría que ver como es el mecanismo al sitio dónde quieres acceder, obviamente no puedo probarlo, por lo que accederemos a una página "demo" como [está](http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/index.php). La página ofrece un formulario como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ingresamos un login válido (por ejemplo: alex/alex) accederemos a esta url: `http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/profile.php`, si no estamos logeados nos redirigirá a la url de login.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea del ejemplo será logearse y obtener la página de esta segunda url, los pasos a seguir no son complicados:

#### 1. Hacer el login

Creamos una sesión mediante `html_session` y conservamos el objeto `session` ya que lo necesitaremos luego para hacer el "scrapping", es muy importante también ubicar el # del formulario de login dentro de la página, en particular si hay más de uno en este ejemplo es el 1.

```
login.url <- "http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/index.php" 
session <- html_session(login.url) # Creamos una sesion
loginform <- html_form(session)[[1]] # Apuntar al form de login
```

Lo siguiente es configurar los valores de usuario y contraseña, esto variará según cada sitio/página, lo importante es ubicar los id´s de los campos de usuario, password y del botón "submit".

```
form <- submit_form(session=session,
                    form=filled_form,
                    submit="submit")
```

#### 2. Captura de páginas dentro de la sesión

Si el login fue exitoso y lo podemos verificar analizando `form$response$url`, podemos ahora sí, "capturar" la página en cuestión

```
url <- jump_to(session, "http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/profile.php")
doc <- read_html(url)
```

En caso de éxito, `doc` contendrá el código html de `http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/profile.php`, en caso de error debiéramos obtener la página de login nuevamente.

El código completo:

```
library(rvest)

# ##########################################################################################
# Login a la página
# ##########################################################################################
login.url <- "http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/index.php" 
session <- html_session(login.url) # Creamos una sesion
loginform <- html_form(session)[[1]] # Apuntar al form de login 

# Completamos los datos de login, esto dependerá de la página
filled_form <- set_values(loginform, username = "alex", password = "alex") 

# Enviamos el formulario
form <- submit_form(session=session,
                    form=filled_form,
                    submit="submit")

# ##########################################################################################
# Vamos a la URL que nos interesa siempre dentro de la sessión en la que no hemos logeado
# ##########################################################################################
url <- jump_to(session, "http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/login-form-php-demo/profile.php")
doc <- read_html(url)
doc
```

En caso que todo funcionase correctamente `doc` sería:

```
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title>Your Home Page </title>\n<link rel= ...
[2] <body>\r\n<div id="profile">\r\n<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i>alex</i></b>\r\n<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Ou ...
>
```

Con el `<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i>alex</i></b>`verificamos que nos hemos logeado exitosamente.

Espero te sirva.